# When is LUKS encrypting my data?

Tags: encryption, luks

Assuming I have a partition encrypted with LUKS, which I mount and read from and write to.

My question is when is the data encrypted? When I write it or when I unmount the partition?

Also, what happens if my system shuts down before I can unmount the partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encryption happens as you write, not on unmount. It would be hard to do that on unmount, as it would mean caching all write operations somewhere in memory before you commit them to disk (and there would be no point in caching them unencrypted on the disk...).
Not counting the fact that it would make it unreliable.

If you force a shutdown without a clean unmount, you'll have the same issue(s) you'd have with regular disk, with possible corruption and missing data... It's a bad idea in general, even when you don't have encrypted your disk :-/

From my small experience, using LUKS-encrypted partitions every day, there's no issue even in case of improper shutdown. The system has always been able to recover when it happened to me. I guess it depends how much you write to your disk, and how lucky you are :-)

EDIT: for reference, LUKS encryptions is based on dm-crypt. I found some data over here:
https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/DMCrypt
Which mention:

> Writes to this device will be encrypted and reads decrypted. You can mount your filesystem on it as usual or stack dm-crypt device with another device like RAID or LVM volume.

My understanding is that this is lower-level compatibility, meant to have the disk shown and used as any other, doing encrypt/decrypt on the fly.

This also answers your question about i-nodes - everything is encrypted in a LUKS partition, not just i-nodes. Encryption happens at the block level, and you can put any filesystem on top of it. So the LUKS system just doesn't know and doesn't care about i-nodes.

Comment: do you have any source for that?

Comment: also, is the actual data of the files encrypted, or just the i-nodes of the filesystem?

Comment: I based my answer on my own user experience, and some experience I have as a system software developper (including disk / block drivers). I'll add some links to my answer to back it up a little though :)